# ArgumentError in Users#index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, production

Showing /home/bdme551/bdme21/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

The @users variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?
Extracted source (around line #4):

```
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
```

I know I am missing something.  But, I couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me, please?  Thank you.

Users_controller

```
def index
    @users = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

Console log

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (The @users variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?):
    1: <% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
    2: <h1>All users</h1>
    3: 
    4: <%= will_paginate %>
    5: 
    6: <ul class="users">
    7:   <% @users.each do |user| %>

app/views/users/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__4020588401683243365_70237529196060'
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.7ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (32.0ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from process_request at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (22.3ms)
  Rendering /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/bdme551/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (39.0ms)
```

Comment: will_paginate @users

Comment: What happens in the `index` action of the `users` controller?

Comment: @Deepak I tried.  It's not working.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Do you have records in users table? looks like you are getting empty result.

Comment: Yes, I do have two users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you simply remove the pagination?

Suppose you lose "will_paginate" on line 4 of your view

and you change your controller action from

@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

to just

@users = User.all

I realize you want the pagination to work, but let's start from a known good and work iteratively towards the working solution you need. You say you have two users, but does User.all find them?

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I am doing now.  It's working now.

Comment: So now try changing that to @users = User.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 5) and see what happens there. This will tell us the exact point at which things break down.

Comment: When I do this, it repeats 5 times with 5 users.  Few minutes back, I used faker gem to create more users.

Comment: so we know that the pagination works too.   Here's the next question though...... what happens if you either puts params.inspect in the controller method or use byebug or pry at that point to inspect params? What does params[:page] work out to?

Answer (score 0):

try get the collection of users in your index action like this

```
@users = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

and in your index.html.erb do this

```
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

Comment: I have included the console log, as requested.  After correcting user_controller, I still get the same ArguementError.

Comment: Yes.  No change in the result.

Comment: I updated the console log and other codes in my question above. Please review it, whenever possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `per_page`

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5) 
end
```

and pass the `@users` variable to `will_paginate`

```
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

Comment: I went ahead and incorporated the changes you asked me to.  Then, I updated the console log and other codes in my question above.  Please review it, whenever possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <%= render user %>
   <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

and something like this for app/views/users/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
```

Comment: I added your code, as specified above.  I still get ArgumentError in Users#index.

Comment: I updated the console log and other codes in my question above. Please review it, whenever possible. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can also try to write **@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])** instead of **@users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])** in your 'index' description of the users controller

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I tried it.  I still get the same error message - ArguementError in Users#index.  I am also doing a lot of research.  Hopefully, someone will help me before that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the Gemfile

`gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'`

and run `bundle install`